# Histórico de versões

Tags: sharepoint

É possível identificar em qual versão de um arquivo (que possui versionamento), está determinado assuntou ou palavra??

Por exemplo, existem 2 versões do documento Teste, onde:

> versão 1, possui o texto: "Teste 1, **Teste 2** e Teste 3".
>
> versão 2, possui o texto: "Teste 1 e Teste 3".

Ao fazer a busca, queria saber onde encontra-se a palavra "Teste 2".
É na versão 1 ou na versão 2? Que neste caso, encontra-se na versão 1.

Comment: Dani, tem como vc tirar print ? Ou qual a versão do Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Dani.
Com o trecho de código abaixo você conseguirá ler o conteúdo de cada versão de um arquivo dentro de uma biblioteca.

```
foreach (SPSite tmpSite in tmpRootColl)
            {
                foreach (SPWeb tmpWeb in tmpSite.AllWebs)
                {
                    foreach (SPList tmpList in tmpWeb.Lists)
                    {
                        if (tmpList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary & tmpList.Title == "Docs")
                        {
                            foreach (SPListItem tmpSPListItem in tmpList.Items)
                            {
                                if (tmpSPListItem.Versions.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    SPListItemVersionCollection tmpVerisionCollection = tmpSPListItem.Versions;

                                    SPFile tmpFile = tmpWeb.GetFile(tmpWeb.Url + "/" + tmpSPListItem.File.Url);

                                    foreach (SPFileVersion tmpSPFileVersion in tmpFile.Versions)
                                    {
                                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tmpSPFileVersion.OpenBinaryStream());
                                        string textoDoc = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Faça alguns testes e modifique conforme necessidade.
Creio que pode partir deste código aí.

Abs

Comment: K2rt'o4, Achei que não precisava customizar .... pensei que tivesse alguma configuração nativa. Obrigada pela resposta.